# Python socket send doesn't send the whole string

Tags: python, string, sockets, python-2.7, send

I am having trouble when I try to send a string from client to server over LAN

code for client:

```
def p():
os.system('tasklist > p.txt')
f = open('p.txt', 'r+')
proc = '''
       '''
for line in f:
    proc+=(line+'\b')

c.send(proc)
```

code for server:

```
def main():
while True:
    command = raw_input('COMMAND >> ')
    s.sendall(command)
    data = s.recv(4096)
    print(data+'\n\n')
```

and I am recieving only part of the data I sent.
I've already tried setting more bytes on **s.recv**, but that didn't really help, the problem persists.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use sendall() for the client part too?

Comment: Tried, but the problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 2):

Ref the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send "Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data."

Check the return value from `c.send(proc)` for the total bytes sent and send more if needed.

E.g. if you are sending 100 chars, and c.send(data) returns 40, then you need to call c.send(data[40:]), and so on.

Alternatively, you might be able to/want to use sendall: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall

Comment: So, I can't just set c.send(proc[0:])? I have to check whenever I recieve an string how much bytes are missing?

Comment: It's the sender's (client) responsibility to check everything has been sent, and the receiver's (server) responsibility to read what it needs to. It looks like you are trying to send structured data over a raw socket, you might want to look at using a simple RPC framework instead as that will take care of a lot of stuff for you. For example, https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html

Comment: sendall(data) saved my life